# How can I modify a Build Definition in TFS using Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, tfsbuild

I am using Eclipse with the Team Foundation Server plug-in (2010) to create Java code to be stored in TFS. I have successfully created a build definition using the wizard and an ANT build.xml file.  However, I would like to modify the build definition to include the ability to set the build quality on successful build so that TFS Deployer will pick up the files and deploy them.

I have found a number of articles on how to create a new build definition from one of the OOB ones, but they all rely on the Visual Studio build processing which has a "process" tab in the New Build Definition wizard.  Java builds do not have the "process" tab, they have a "project" tab.  I also understand that this project tab uses the upgrade template.

How would I modify my processing so that I can set the build quality?  Should this be done in the TFSBuld.proj file, by somehow modifying the build template, or maybe even in the ANT build script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you cannot modify the XAML process that the build definition uses from Eclipse.  However - you could modify the build definition from Visual Studio to use a modified  UpgradeTemplate if you wanted to set the build quality in the process template XAML.

Alternatively, you could modify the TFSBuild.proj file associated with the build and get it to set the build quality by adding a target similar to this:

```
<Target Name="AfterDropBuild">
    <SetBuildProperties TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
                        BuildUri="$(BuildUri)" 
                        Quality="Ready for Deployment" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Another update - I got the override to work and the build quality set by adding the target after the import statements. I must have done something wrong yesterday. Thank you, Martin, for your assistance. And I also want to complement you on your book, *Professional Team Foundation Server 2010*, which has been a great help to me in implementing TFS at our organization.